# Custom chakra theme is slow on load

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, chakra-ui

In our project, we have AngularJS at the core and we are transitioning to React. On the React side, we are using Chakra UI with a customized theme.

When loading React component we are wrapping the component with ChakraProvider with a custom theme, and it looks something like that:

```
<DesignProvider>
  <FolderPermissionsIndicator {...props} />
</DesignProvider>
```

Where `DesignProvider` is:

```
import { ChakraProvider, ChakraProviderProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { theme } from './theme';
import { useMemo } from 'react';

export const DesignProvider: React.FC<ChakraProviderProps> = props => {
  const themeInstance = useMemo(() => theme, []);

  return (
    <div data-ds-next={true}>
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS={false} {...props} theme={themeInstance} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the theme is:

```
const theme: ChakraTheme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      ...gigantic object...
    }
  }
});
```

Now, this works great, but if we have a lot of components embedded into AngularJS, and each separately is wrapped with `DesignProvider` things are getting slow.
In particular, merging the global theme costomizations are taking some time. As an example, if we remove the `global` object from a theme, once of the pages load can go from ~20sec to ~500ms.

One of the workarounds is of course pulling that `global` portion into a css file and load it globally. This solution comes with its own complications though.

Is there an easier way to share a customized theme across all the components?

Comment: You could use your component DesignProvider to wrap the component <App /> in index.js.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil right, in the normal situation that is true. However, as I described, we have a bunch of React components embedded into Angular app. That means that we have to instantiate them separately and wrap them with providers like redux provider, chakra provider, etc...  for redux and others we can easily share the same objects for providers. In case of chakra provider it builds up the theme inside the provider itself, which is in our case ends up being very slow.

Comment: In this case, try to use context API, it will help you to resolve your problem, you could check for more details in my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**Context API**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is a solution for your problem, create context theme where you could store your theme object.

From React doc:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for
> a tree of React components, such as the currently authenticated user,
> theme, or preferred language.

theme-context.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme :null
});

const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
  const theme: ChakraTheme = extendTheme({
    styles: {
      global: {
        ...gigantic object...
      }
    }
  });
  const [themeState] = useState(theme); 
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{ theme:  themeState}}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

Component DesignProvider:

```
import { ChakraProvider, ChakraProviderProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeContext } from './theme-context';
import { useMemo, useContext } from 'react';

export const DesignProvider: React.FC<ChakraProviderProps> = props => {
  const themeInstance = useMemo(() => theme, []);
  const them = useContext(ThemeContext).theme;

  return (
    <div data-ds-next={true}>
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS={false} {...props} theme={theme} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Last step: wrapp your App with **ThemeContextProvider**:

```
<ThemeContextProvider>
  <App/>
</ThemeContextProvider>
```

So every time you use your component **DesignProvider** you will not reuse your giant object, you will get them from ThemeContext at runtime.

Comment: This is not really helping as I don't have the top level `App` to wrap. All I have is several react components injected into Angular app.